# Enable contextmenu after disabling it once

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I am working on a project that was worked on by some students in the past and hence the code quality is not as good as it should be. I am trying to enable the context menu that comes up when a user right clicks but it isn't happening.

Link: [Click here to visit the project](http://clausehound.com/documents/)

I have tried the following that should reverse any preventDefault() function, but it won't work. It should be simple to resolve this issue but somehow the context menu won't show. Any ideas?

```
$(window).bind("contextmenu", function () {
            return true;
});
```

I cannot find the reason why contextmenu is disabled in the first place and hence this solution. I have tried that with 'body' as well, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't believe you can un-do preventDefault, you should try avoiding it in the first place.

Comment: Your linked page loads 4 different jQuery versions too. I don't think that helps in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.oncontextmenu = null;` is enough to kill this (in this case), but make sure to call it after that script was called:

You could also remove this code from the body (at the top):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.oncontextmenu = function(e){
                    var t = e || window.event;
                    var elm = t.target || t.srcElement;
                    if(elm.nodeName == "A" || elm.type == 'text' || elm.type == 'password') 
                        return true;
                        return false;
                }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind`

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

> Robust and extensible applications typically demand the two-argument
>   version for this reason:
>
> ```
> var handler = function() {
>   alert( "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." );
> };
> $( "#foo" ).bind( "click", handler );
> $( "#foo" ).unbind( "click", handler );
> ```
>
> By naming the handler, we can be assured that no other functions are
>   accidentally removed.

So just name that handler:

```
 var handler = function() {
   return false;
 };
 $( window ).bind( "contextmenu", handler );
 $( window ).unbind( "contextmenu", handler );
```

Comment: If so, jQuery seems to remove both. But how did you test it, if you don't have the handler here?

Comment: @CodeiSir Sorry, my bad, I misunderstood the question a bit :)

Comment: @CodeiSir My point was that in general you can bind/unbind contextmenu. You're right :)

Comment: Np, on my side I still learned something new about jQuery, thank you ;)